# Passing all data from database into arrays as the application starts

Tags: android

My question is not "how?" but "should I?".

I got the app that uses access to database very often. It's money manager basically. It uses data to make calculations, draw a charts and stuff.

I was wondering if the accessing database every ocasion I need some data is efficent way, especially when database grows larger.

Is it a good idea of making class that would read all the database tables into multidimensional arrays for further use of the application? I would read it in a thread with some progress bar if necessary, and then I would have much more efficient way of accesiing datas from arrays right?

Please be gentle with me, as I could be totally wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is a good idea. If your data grows large, you can easily run out of memory. Unless you are sure you wouldn't have that much data, or you need to read them to memory anyway. How much data you are talking about? And how much of them you actually need on the screen?

Comment: How much hmm, i don't know if you are familiar with money manager apps. But it's basically just few tables average 4 columns each. Most of users gets bored with such app before they grow their database really really large :P